# Sencha Cmd - Error executing page compilation Circular extends reference for class Sample.deadlock

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-cmd

I'm trying to compile my **Ext JS 4.1.1.a** based application using **64-bit Linux OS**. 
Here's my application hierarchy(*Maven based Java Web Application*):

```
+ src
     +main
         +webapp
             + extjs
             + app
             - app.js
             - index.jsp
             + resources
             + WEB-INF
```

Command:

```
sencha compile -classpath=extjs/src,js page -yui -in index.jsp -out build/index.jsp
```

It's a huge project, so I'd like to learn how can I find the classes that generates error. Here is the error stacktrace:

```
[ERROR]     Circular extends reference :
Sample.deadlock.A ->
Sample.deadlock.B ->
Sample.deadlock.E ->
Sample.deadlock.C ->
Sample.deadlock.D ->
Sample.deadlock.A
[ERROR]     Error executing page compilation Circular extends reference for class Sample.deadlock.A
[ERROR]     com.sencha.exceptions.ExCircularReference: Circular extends reference for class Sample.deadlock.A
```

Comment: What is the command line you are using, and what folder are you issuing it from?

Comment: updated first post, added the command that I used.

Answer (score 3):

I've made the same mistake following [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command_app_single).

I assumed `extjs/src` is the extjs source folder. But this is not correct.

The correct command to run is:

```
sencha -sdk ../ext-4.1.1a compile -classpath=js page -yui -in index.jsp -out build/index.jsp
```

Comment: Sometime I really hate Sencha's documentation.  It's typically sparse or flat out wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's an example that shows deadlock detection. That's why the class is prefixed with "Sample". Remove it from your project.

Comment: after removing this samples, it doesn't generate any errors. But the problem now is the **all-classes.js** being empty!

Comment: Same issue here. How do I 'remove sample from my project'. If I delete the `/src/core/examples` I get a a different error `[ERR]        Failed to find file for @core required by /Library/WebServer/Documents/v4/submission/../ext-4.1.1a/src/direct/Provider.js`